# Add element to JsValue?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to add in a new element to a JsValue, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
 val rJson = Json.parse(response)
 val imgId = //stuff to get the id :Long
 rJson.apply("imgId", imgId) 
 Json.stringify(rJson)
```

Should I be converting to a JSONObject or is there some method that can be applied directly to the JsValue to insert a new element to the JSON?

Edit:

`response` is coming from another server, but I do have control over it. So, if I need to add an empty `"imgId"` element to the JSON Object, that's fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this as a `JsObject`, which extends `JsValue` and has a `+` method:

```
val rJson: JsValue = Json.parse(response)
val imgId = ...
val returnJson: JsObject = rJson.as[JsObject] + ("imgId" -> Json.toJson(imgId))
Json.stringify(returnJson)
```

Comment: Note that `Json.parse` is not safe - it will throw an exception if the `response` cannot be parsed. Nor is `as[JsObject]` is safe - it will throw an exception if the `JsValue` cannot be read as a `JsObject`. I recommend reading the Play JSON docs before using this answer.

Comment: `Json.parse` is irrelevant to the answer. The only part that matters is line 3.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following helper in a project I'm working on:

```
/** Insert a new value at the given path */
def insert(path: JsPath, value: JsValue) =
  __.json.update(path.json.put(value))
```

, which can be used as a JSON transformer as such:

```
val rJson = Json.parse(response)
val imgId = //stuff to get the id :Long
Json.stringify(rJson.transform(insert(__ \ 'imgId, imgId)))
```

You could definitely just use the body of that `insert` method, but I personally find the transformer API to be really counterintuitive.

The nice thing about this is that any number of transforms can be composed using `andThen`. We typically use this to convert API responses to the format of our models so that we can use `Reads` deserializers to instantiate model instances. We use this `insert` helper to mock parts of the API response that don't yet exist, so that we can build models we need ahead of the API.

Even though the API is convoluted, I highly, highly recommend investing some time in reading the [Play framework docs on JSON handling](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson), all 5 pages. They're not the world's greatest docs, but they actually are pretty thorough.

Comment: Makes perfect sense in hindsight. You're right about the docs -  thorough, however quite rambling. They had me thinking that I could only transform with `JsPath.json.put` alone, which is fairly lossy...